# Select records from the resultant array in php based on a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming and i was searching for this and couldn't find the answer.
This is my php code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","databasename");

$query = "select values from table where condition1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

So, What I need is basically i want to again select some records from this variable.
Like,

```
$set1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result where $result[column_name] = value1";
$set2 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result where $result[column_name] = value2";
$set3 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result where $result[column_name] = value3";
```

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You can't select from a variable. Can you give a more specific example of the kind of data you're working with? That would help us give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

well .. to answer your question, you need `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to transform the database `row` to an `array`

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

so, you can try this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","databasename");

$sql = "select values from table where condition1"; 

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

then, your `$result[column_name]` should be available :

```
$set1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result[table_name] where $result[column_name] = 'value1'");
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set1 );

$set2 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result[table_name] where $result[column_name] = 'value2'");
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set2 );

$set3 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result[table_name] where $result[column_name] = 'value3'");
$result3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But it is giving me an error like this:                     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: and also my value1, value2 and value3 are strings.

Comment: are they variables ?

Comment: No.They are just strings.So My Query is  $set1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from $result where $result['column_name'] = 'value1'");

Comment: Yeah.But i want those from the result variable and not from the table.  $set1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select values from **$result** where $result['column_name'] = 'value1'");

Comment: oh so the tables names are in the `$result` ? what are you expecting from `$result` ?

Comment: I want to select the rows in the $result based on a condition.  So the column value which is equal to 'value1' should go to one variable and those equal to 'value2' should go into an another variable.

Comment: but I want the records which are in $result and i don't want all of them which are in the table.

Comment: i just edited my answer to the best of my understanding, i hope that helps or at least gives you a hint for what you want to do,